# How build Single-Sign-On on Zimbra

Tags: java, web-services, soap, single-sign-on, zimbra

How to Build a SSO with Zimbra?
Soon after the User enter the zimbra, how to get the credentials via SOAP in Zimbra?

See step 4.

[image]

Comment: I found this link, https://www.jorgedelacruz.es/2014/10/24/zimbra-configurando-spnego-sso-paso-a-paso/

Comment: Other link using saml
https://blog.zimbra.com/2010/06/using-saml-assertions-to-access-zimbra/?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=twitter&utm_content=twitter